# Find an element in a PriorityQueue by key

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue

Suppose I've been given some key. What I'd like to find is an element in the priority queue such that it's key equal or greater than the given key.

Obviously, I want to it to be done in `O(logn)`. I'm almost certain Java offers such method yet couldn't find it (looked in the official docs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such method.

The underlying implementation of priority queue is min heap (it can be configured to act as min heap as well). So for a priority queue with max heap property, when you check the peek element (which is `O(1)` operation), it will return the maximum element. After polling it out, heapify-ing will be performed and the next top element will be the second maximum. This heapify-ing in of `O(logn)` complexity. So, if you want to get all keys greater or equal to a given key, you need to keep polling from max-heap priority queue until top element is less than given key. And in worst case, this can be `O(nlogn)`.

Also after these operations, the queue structured will be altered as some of the keys had been polled. So before next operation, you have to restore your queue's state by re-pushing the polled keys which will be `O(nlogn)` too.

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(10, Collections.reverseOrder())

List<Integer> keysGreaterOrEqualTo(Integer key) {
    List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<>();
    while(!queue.isEmpty() && queue.peek() >= key) {
        keys.add(queue.poll());
    }
    return keys;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a non-destructive way to do it. Rather than removing things from the queue until you find one that meets your criteria, you can use the [iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator()) to search.

Understand that the iterator will not return items in any particular order, so if you want the smallest item that's greater than or equal to some value, you still have to iterate over the entire collection.

The complexity of this is obviously O(n). The complexity of the destructive technique described in the accepted answer is O(k log n), where `k` is the number of items that are smaller than the one you're searching for. In the worst case, `k=n`, and the algorithm is O(n log n).

Answer (score 1):

Java Priority Queue has `contains()` method which returns true if a key is found in the Priority Queue.
Refrence - [Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

To find a key greater than or equal to you can implement your own custom method. Such as :

```
int searchkey = 5, foundKey = 0;

While(!pq.isEmpty()){
  foundKey = pq.poll();   
  if(foundKey == searchKey || foundKey > searchKey)
    break;
}
System.out.println(foundKey == searchKey || foundKey > searchKey ? foundKey : -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be better off using the TreeSet instead, specifically it's tailSet method. It can be used like a priority queue and it's also N log N.